# How to return the highest value from a multi dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a multi dimensional array like the following:

```
[
   [.1, .2, .9],
   [.3, .4, .5],
   [.2, .4, .8]
]
```

What would be the best* way to return a single dimension array that contains the highest value from each sub-array (`[.9,.5,.8]`)?  I assume I could do it manually doing something like below:

```
newArray = []
for subarray in array:
   maxItem = 0
   for item in subarray:
       if item > maxItem:
           maxItem = item
   newArray.append(maxItem)
```

But I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to do this?

*In this case best = fewest lines of code

Comment: Are you using Numpy or not?

Comment: Yes, I am using Numpy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment that you are using numpy ...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(3,3)
>>> a
array([[ 0.43852835,  0.07928864,  0.33829191],
       [ 0.60776121,  0.02688291,  0.67274362],
       [ 0.2188034 ,  0.58202254,  0.44704166]])
>>> a.max(axis=1)
array([ 0.43852835,  0.67274362,  0.58202254])
```

---

**edit:**  the documentation is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

Comment: Interesting, would you recommend this method over using `map`/`max`?  If so, why?

Comment: Yes, these kind of operations are the strength of numpy ndarrays.  It will be faster and efficient because implementation detail is C code.

Comment: you may get back the exact right floats also (Im not entirely sure you can rely on that... float precision is weird)

Comment: Can you point me towards some documentation for this or explain what `axis=1` is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Based on your link it seems that `amax` is the same as `max`.  Is this correct?

Comment: added docs link to my answer.  axis=1 refers to working on rows in this 2d case (axis=0, in contrast, would be getting you the max in each column)

Comment: Yes, `np.amax(a, axis=1)` is equivalent to `a.max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
max(array.flatten())
```

Answer (score 11):

`map` with `max` is cleaner IMO.

```
>>> arr = [
...    [.1, .2, .9],
...    [.3, .4, .5],
...    [.2, .4, .8]
... ]
>>> map(max, arr)
[0.9, 0.5, 0.8]
```

[map documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: Always forget about functional programming options.

Comment: But if the arr is a numpy.Arrary object,>>> s
array([[ 0.1,  0.2,  0.9],
       [ 0.3,  0.4,  0.5],
       [ 0.2,  0.4,  0.8]]) the result is >>> map(max, s)
[0.90000000000000002, 0.5, 0.80000000000000004], why?

Comment: Scratch that.  I also got the results that Sheng is getting.  Not a huge deal, but an interesting oddity.

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension:

```
maxed = [max(sub_array) for sub_array in array]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 map(max,my_array)
```

I think thats pretty short ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of the second for loop just use the [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
w = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[1,2,11]]
h=[]
for i in w:
    h.append(np.amax(i))
print(h)
```