# Fast code for finding the max value of a 2d array

Tags: python

I've read a lot of answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917076/how-to-return-the-highest-value-from-a-multi-dimensional-array) so it's *not* a duplicate (especially with the way I read the value). Is there a **faster** code for this:

```
mx = 0
for i in range(0, len(self.board)):
    for j in range(0, len(self.board[i])):
        for k in range(0, len(self.board[i][j]['b'])):
            l = self.board[i][j]['b'][k]
            mx = max([mx, l.get('id', 0)])
```

in Python? Maybe with `map` but I dont see how?

Each "cell" of the board is a dict like that

- `'b'` = array of dicts: each dicts contains an information about a piece of a game, example: `{'id':3, 'nb':1, 'kind':'bee'}`. We can have many pieces on the same cell (one piece on top of another one)
- `'p'` = array of ids of the pieces above if we can put them on this cell
- `'h'` = array of `'kind'` of pieces that are not yet on the board but we can put on this cell

FYI I pre-calculate the whole board before sending it in JSON to a JavaScript client, so that I can do all pre-calculation in Python, and have to code as few as possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Faster than `O(n^3)`? It looks like you have a 3D array...

Comment: Is the array sorted in some way?

If the array has no ordering there is no faster way than looking at all the elements which is `O(n^2)`

Comment: No, this is an array with informations about pieces of a game

Comment: Could you also provide what is the structure of the `board`? Is it a 2d array of `dict` objects? And, what is `m` in `max([m, l.get('id', 0)])`? Is it `mx`?

Comment: @AKS Edited my question

Comment: @AKS it's not `m` it's `mx`, syntax error corrected

Comment: You may be able to optimize your code using other iteration protocols, `for` when I tested it using `timeit` module performed slower, this is true for my platform and the results may differ from one platform to another, but as a rule of thump, you should write for simplicity and code readability, then optimize. If you  think optimizing will make your code look more complicated and harder to decipher then I would suggest moving to [Pypy](http://pypy.org/). Don't forget to take into your account that the speed of your code isn' limited to the code itself, other variables also play out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a board which have rows with cells and each cell have multiple pieces.

You can use list comprehension to get all the ids and then get the `max of it:

```
max(piece.get('id', 0) for row in self.board for cell in row for piece in cell['b'])
```

I am not sure how fast it would be (*will ofcourse depend on how big your board is*) but I am pretty sure it would faster than the 3 for loops and calculating max on each iteration.

Comment: Oh my god. I was pretty sure there was such a nice solution! Thank you very much indeed!